# when we upload .rvt files, we always got the error message "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure". the file is not corrupted we have checked

Tags: autodesk-forge

```
{
"type": "manifest",
"hasThumbnail": "false",
"status": "failed",
"progress": "complete",
"region": "US",
"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YWRhbV8yMDE3LTA1LTI4X3RhdGFzdGVlbDEvcnN0X2Jhc2ljX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0LnJ2dA",
"version": "1.0",
"derivatives": [
    {
        "name": "LMV Bubble",
        "hasThumbnail": "false",
        "status": "failed",
        "progress": "complete",
        "messages": [
            {
                "type": "error",
                "message": "Tr worker fail to download.",
                "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
            }
        ],
        "outputType": "svf"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hello anuradha, your question seem to lack some explanation aswell as a coding block to better visualize your json. Could you please add a phrase to better understand your question and a code block for your json? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide your request body to Forge MD POST Jobs API?

Answer (score 0):

According to your urn, there would be a great possibility that your model is RVT. So, please retry with this request payload:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'x-ads-force: true' \
  -d '{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YWRhbV8yMDE3LTA1LTI4X3RhdGFzdGVlbDEvcnN0X2Jhc2ljX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0LnJ2dA"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

**Note. Now Forge Model Derivative API only supports RVT files come from Revit 2016-2020.**